# Editing django-rest-framework serializer object before save

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to edit a `django-rest-framwork` serializer object before it is saved. This is how I currently do it -

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
             obj = form.save(commit=False)
             obj.user_id = 15
             obj.save()
```

How can I do it with a `django-rest-framework` serializer object?

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def upload_serializers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         serializer = FilesSerializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
         if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
```

Comment: Your first paragraph seems incomplete. “This how I do it with” what?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can edit the serializer's object before save the serializer:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.object.user_id = 15 # <----- this line
    serializer.save()
```

Comment: Can one modify a nested object ?
serializer.object.book.author_id = 22

Comment: `serializer.validated_data['user_id'] = 15` works on 3.8.2

Comment: Serializer object has no attribute 'object'.

Answer (score 79):

**Now edited for REST framework 3**

With REST framework 3 the pattern is now:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(user_id=15)
```

Note that the serializers do *not* now ever expose an unsaved object instance as `serializer.object`, however you *can* inspect the raw validated data as `serializer.validated_data`.

If you're using the generic views and you want to modify the save behavior you can use the `perform_create` and/or `perform_update` hooks...

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user_id=15)
```

Comment: It looks like this has changed to `perform_create()` in DRF 3.x.

Comment: Hint: inside the `perform_create()` method, you can access `self.request`, `self.args`, and `self.kwargs`.

Comment: This can not be used when we need conditional modification.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need to modify the data before validation, there is another option without needing to override the functions `create` or `perform_create`. Just use the `to_internal_value` function on your serializers class:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data['field1'] = "new value for field 1"
        data['field2'] = "new value for field 2"
        data['field3'] = "new value for field 3"
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

So we can modify the data before doing the validation.