# DJANGO - Save data with genericforeignkey on POST method using rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, generic-foreign-key

I would like to save an instance of 'Feedback' object on my database, the feedback object have a foreignkey to 'Client', and a genericforeignkey because it can be related to 'Vendor' or 'Store', i made 2 url's that allows POST, one to create feedback for vendor and another to create feedback for store, both receive the primarykey.

Class diagram example:
[image: Class Diagram]

This is my approach:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def store_feedback_view(request, store_id):
    serializer = FeedbackSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The serializer is valid, but while trying to save give me the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: feedback_feedback.object_id
NOT NULL constraint failed: feedback_feedback.content_type_id
```

This happens because the feedback object have the genericforeignkey not NULL:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comment', max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name="Client feedback", related_name="feedbacks")

    limit = models.Q(app_label='core', model='store') | models.Q(app_label='core', model='vendor')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     limit_choices_to=limit)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Related object ID")
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'feedback'
```

How i can create an object of feedback on POST method?

This is a example of request on `feedback/store/(?P<store_id>\d+)/`

```
{
  "comment": "Nice store",
  "client": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set store to serializer.object:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def store_feedback_view(request, store_id):
    serializer = FeedbackSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # this line added:
        serializer.object.content_object = get_object_or_404(Store, id=store_id)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: This is for versions of DRF older than DRF 3.0. See here for how this should be handled in 3.0+: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13564519/2133271