# Check object permission before create in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Using ModelViewSet and DjangoObjectPermissions.

Django REST framework seems to not call check_object_permission for a "create" request (POST).
I need to check the user is allowed to create THIS object before it's saved into database (because permission check depend of object values)

I suppose I need to override "create" method of the ModelViewSet but I didn't know how to get the instance from serializer without saving it to database.

1. How to get the object instance from serializer without saving to database ?
2. Or how to have DRF check for object permission for a POST/create request ?

Thanks

EDIT:

After deeping into DRF code, I'm able to get the instance without save :

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = WorkedHourSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = MyModel(**serializer.validated_data)
```

But Django refuse to check perm for an object without primary key so I have to force one :

```
        instance.id = 0
        self.check_object_permissions(request, instance)
```

Comment: Where does `check_object_permissions` come from? Do you use a library for that?

Comment: it's from REST framework API : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no way to get the instance before saving it ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13564519/3334049))
2. The best approach would seem to be to implement a custom permission (probably subclassing `rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission` or `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated`) and adding the logic of permission checking in `has_permission(self, request, view)` ([see more](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)). This way, you would access `request.user` and then you would be able to determine whether that user has permission to create that object.

Comment: The problem is more generic, in a update request, the `check_object_permission` is called in `get_object` which use the object version in database and not the data sent by client. So i've written a Mixin to apply on ModelViewSet which perform check_object_permission on object sent by client and before it's saved into database (see below)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create a Mixin to apply on `ModelViewSet` which perform check_object_permission with an instance created using request.data and not object retrieved from database before the data are saved to database :

```
import uuid


class CheckObjectPermissionBeforeSaveMixin():

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check_instance_from_data_permission(request)
        return super(CheckObjectPermissionBeforeSaveMixin, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check_instance_from_data_permission(request)
        return super(CheckObjectPermissionBeforeSaveMixin, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check_instance_from_data_permission(request)
        return super(CheckObjectPermissionBeforeSaveMixin, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def check_instance_from_data_permission(self, request):
        instance = self.get_instance_from_data(request.data)
        if instance:
            self.check_object_permissions(request, instance)

    def get_instance_from_data(self, data):
        ModelClass = self.serializer_class.Meta.model
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = ModelClass(**serializer.validated_data)
            instance.id = data.get('id') or uuid.uuid4().hex  # Django's has_perm need a primary key to be set...
            return instance
        return None


class MyModelViewSet(CheckObjectPermissionBeforeSaveMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a massive security flaw in my view. Another way of securing it - if not generating nice HTML responses is to write a custom Model Serializer if you're using both it and the REST API Views / ViewSets and are using Object Level Permissions:

```
class CreatePermModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
def create(self, validated_data):
    obj = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
    view = self._context['view']
    request = self._context['request']
    for permission in view.permission_classes:
        if not permission.has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            raise ValueError('not authorized')
    super(CreatePermModelSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Something about security flaws.**

Django DRF permissions system works well to enforce permissions on objects related to other objects...

... But you might have what I would call a "root object" in your app : an object which is only related to a userid.

While testing my app, I noticed, that a logged in user could create such "root object" for another user.

Example that have a security flow :

models.py :

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

permissions.py :
You would use `IsOwner` in the permission classes of your associated viewset.

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        obj = MyObject.objects.get(pk=view.kwargs['something'])
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

While this will restrict accessing objects belonging to the logged in user, it won't disallow a logged in user to CREATE an object belonging to ANOTHER user.

I used to let the frontend fill the "owner" property.
Like posting this (that's easy to guess that user 1 exists) :

```
{
    "name": "A prank object",
    "owner": 1,
}
```

Object level permission (has_object_permission) cannot be used here. It just won't be called.

Therefore, a malicious user could create "prank objects" that could ruin your user experience.

Actually, Django DRF gives a [simple solution](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users)

In your viewset.py :

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
     serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

And, as the owner property is now managed by Django DRF, this field can by excluded from your serializer Meta. Therefore your REST API is less exposed.

Then whatever a potentially malicious user would post as a owner, it will be replaced by its own id and therefore not disturbing other users...

Well, and using UUID as userid instead of incremental integers may be a good advice, as probability to guess other userid will be low.

Comment: The DRF solution is cool, but isn't `obj.owner == request.user` going to prevent a logged in user to CREATE an object belonging to ANOTHER user?